# Pandas read_html results in TypeError

Tags: python, pandas

I'm using bs4 to parse a html page and extract a table, sample table given below and I'm trying to load it into pandas but when i call `pddataframe = pd.read_html(LOTable,skiprows=2, flavor=['bs4'])` I get the error listed below but I can print the tables prettified by bs4

Any suggestions how I can resolve this without needing to get each td and read in 1 by 1?

### Sample Table

```
<table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" class="borders" width="100%">
    <tr>
     <th colspan="2">
      Learning Outcomes
     </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td class="info" colspan="2">
      On successful completion of this module the learner will be able to:
     </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td style="width:10%;">
      LO1
     </td>
     <td>
      Demonstrate an awareness of the important role of Financial Accounting information as an input into the decision making process.
     </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td style="width:10%;">
      LO2
     </td>
     <td>
      Display an understanding of the fundamental accounting concepts, principles and conventions that underpin the preparation of Financial statements.
     </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td style="width:10%;">
      LO3
     </td>
     <td>
      Understand the various formats in which  information in relation to transactions or events is recorded and classified.
     </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td style="width:10%;">
      LO4
     </td>
     <td>
      Apply a knowledge of accounting concepts,conventions and techniques such as double entry to the  posting of  recorded information to the T accounts in the Nominal Ledger.
     </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td style="width:10%;">
      LO5
     </td>
     <td>
      Prepare and present the financial statements of a Sole Trader  in prescribed format from a Trial Balance  accompanies by notes with additional information.
     </td>
    </tr>
   </table>
```

### Error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------  TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last) <ipython-input-20-12673b1a4bfc> in <module>()
     10         #Read table into pandas
     11         if first:
---> 12             pddataframe = pd.read_html(LOTable,skiprows=2, flavor=['bs4'])
     13             first = False
     14             pddataframe

C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\envs\LearningOutcomes\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\html.py in read_html(io, match, flavor, header, index_col, skiprows, attrs, parse_dates, tupleize_cols, thousands, encoding)
    872     _validate_header_arg(header)
    873     return _parse(flavor, io, match, header, index_col, skiprows,
--> 874                   parse_dates, tupleize_cols, thousands, attrs, encoding)

C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\envs\LearningOutcomes\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\html.py in _parse(flavor, io, match, header, index_col, skiprows, parse_dates, tupleize_cols, thousands, attrs, encoding)
    734             break
    735     else:
--> 736         raise_with_traceback(retained)
    737 
    738     ret = []

C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\envs\LearningOutcomes\lib\site-packages\pandas\compat\__init__.py in raise_with_traceback(exc, traceback)
    331         if traceback == Ellipsis:
    332             _, _, traceback = sys.exc_info()
--> 333         raise exc.with_traceback(traceback)
    334 else:
    335     # this version of raise is a syntax error in Python 3

**TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable**
```

Comment: `flavor : str or None, container of strings` in [`pandas.read_html`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_html.html).

Comment: tried it without flavor='bs4'  pd.read_html(LOTable,skiprows=2) and got the same error. I can call print (LOTable.prettify()) prior to attempting to read and the table html is outputted then the error @AKS I don't follow your comment could you explain a bit more please?

Comment: problem is with your sample or with real data?

Answer (score 8):

Thanks for the pointers from all the suggested answers and comments, my rookie mistake was I had the table in a variable after extracting it using bs4.
I was running `pd.read_html(LOTable,skiprows=2, flavor='bs4')` when I needed to run `pd.read_html(LOTable.prettify(),skiprows=2, flavor='bs4')`

Comment: Thanks for telling us. I suspected that. My reading of recent pandas documentation suggested that putting `flavor='bs4'` in is unnecessary because panda would default to lxml IIRC. That's what suggested to me that it does the parsing itself, or at least that it handles the parsing without the need for the user to do so.

Answer (score 1):

Pandas can guess.

```
HTML = '''\
<table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" class="borders" width="100%">
    <tr>
     <th colspan="2">
      Learning Outcomes
     </th>


... omitting most of what you had here


      Prepare and present the financial statements of a Sole Trader  in prescribed format from a Trial Balance  accompanies by notes with additional information.
     </td>
    </tr>
   </table>'''

from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_html(StringIO(HTML))
print (df)
```

Result:

```
[                                                   0  \
0                                  Learning Outcomes   
1  On successful completion of this module the le...   
2                                                LO1   
3                                                LO2   
4                                                LO3   
5                                                LO4   
6                                                LO5   

                                                   1  
0                                                NaN  
1                                                NaN  
2  Demonstrate an awareness of the important role...  
3  Display an understanding of the fundamental ac...  
4  Understand the various formats in which inform...  
5  Apply a knowledge of accounting concepts,conve...  
6  Prepare and present the financial statements o...  ]
```

Answer (score 1):

This exact code works for me.

```
htm = """<table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" class="borders" width="100%">
    <tr>
     <th colspan="2">
      Learning Outcomes
     </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td class="info" colspan="2">
      On successful completion of this module the learner will be able to:
     </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td style="width:10%;">
      LO1
     </td>
     <td>
      Demonstrate an awareness of the important role of Financial Accounting information as an input into the decision making process.
     </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td style="width:10%;">
      LO2
     </td>
     <td>
      Display an understanding of the fundamental accounting concepts, principles and conventions that underpin the preparation of Financial statements.
     </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td style="width:10%;">
      LO3
     </td>
     <td>
      Understand the various formats in which  information in relation to transactions or events is recorded and classified.
     </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td style="width:10%;">
      LO4
     </td>
     <td>
      Apply a knowledge of accounting concepts,conventions and techniques such as double entry to the  posting of  recorded information to the T accounts in the Nominal Ledger.
     </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td style="width:10%;">
      LO5
     </td>
     <td>
      Prepare and present the financial statements of a Sole Trader  in prescribed format from a Trial Balance  accompanies by notes with additional information.
     </td>
    </tr>
   </table> 
"""

pd.read_html(htm, skiprows=2, flavor='bs4')[0]
```

[image]