# Web scraping a table and passing it to a Pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to web scrape a table with prices of silver.  I read the text data but I can not import them into a pandas dataframe.

In particular, I am trying first to write the content to a txt file and then read it to a Pandas dataframe.  At that point I am getting an exception.

Is there a way to pass the data directly to a Pandas dataframe without first saving them in a text file?

My code is the following:

```
import requests

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.usagold.com/reference/prices/silverhistory.php'

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}

response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
tables = soup.find_all('table', rules = 'all')

table = tables[0]

with open ('silver_prices.txt', 'w') as r:


    for row in table.find_all('tr'):
        for cell in row.find_all('td'):
            r.write(cell.text)
        r.write('\n')

pd.read_csv('silver_prices.txt')
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnicodeDecodeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-113-9cad0b29d24e> in <module>()
----> 1 pd.read_csv('silver_prices.txt')

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Anaconda3_64\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in parser_f(filepath_or_buffer, sep, delimiter, header, names, index_col, usecols, squeeze, prefix, mangle_dupe_cols, dtype, engine, converters, true_values, false_values, skipinitialspace, skiprows, skipfooter, nrows, na_values, keep_default_na, na_filter, verbose, skip_blank_lines, parse_dates, infer_datetime_format, keep_date_col, date_parser, dayfirst, iterator, chunksize, compression, thousands, decimal, lineterminator, quotechar, quoting, doublequote, escapechar, comment, encoding, dialect, tupleize_cols, error_bad_lines, warn_bad_lines, delim_whitespace, low_memory, memory_map, float_precision)
    700                     skip_blank_lines=skip_blank_lines)
    701 
--> 702         return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    703 
    704     parser_f.__name__ = name

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Anaconda3_64\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    427 
    428     # Create the parser.
--> 429     parser = TextFileReader(filepath_or_buffer, **kwds)
    430 
    431     if chunksize or iterator:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Anaconda3_64\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in __init__(self, f, engine, **kwds)
    893             self.options['has_index_names'] = kwds['has_index_names']
    894 
--> 895         self._make_engine(self.engine)
    896 
    897     def close(self):

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Anaconda3_64\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in _make_engine(self, engine)
   1120     def _make_engine(self, engine='c'):
   1121         if engine == 'c':
-> 1122             self._engine = CParserWrapper(self.f, **self.options)
   1123         else:
   1124             if engine == 'python':

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Anaconda3_64\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in __init__(self, src, **kwds)
   1851         kwds['usecols'] = self.usecols
   1852 
-> 1853         self._reader = parsers.TextReader(src, **kwds)
   1854         self.unnamed_cols = self._reader.unnamed_cols
   1855 

pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.__cinit__()

pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._get_header()

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xa0 in position 0: invalid start byte
```

Comment: There is no value in editing this question to hide the URL, as it has been referred to in the answer below. At any rate, it is also available [in the edit history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57173815/revisions). In general, once answers have been given to a question, it is a good idea at that point to only do minor edits (the gold standard is to make sure that the answer(s) are logical  responses to the new version of the question - if an edit makes old answers confusing then it is not a good edit).

Answer (score 1):

You can use StringIO to avoid saving to a file

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from StringIO import StringIO
import pandas as pd
import requests

url = 'https://www.usagold.com/reference/prices/silverhistory.php'

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}

response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
tables = soup.find_all('table', rules = 'all')

table = tables[0]

df = pd.read_html(StringIO(table), skiprows=2, flavor='bs4')[0]
print(df.head())
```

Much of this answer is just stolen from answers to this previous question: [Pandas read_html results in TypeError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41651350/pandas-read-html-results-in-typeerror) maybe a duplicate

**EDIT**

The above works for python2, but StringIO fails for some reason in python3. You don't need StringIO though, just cast `table` to a string:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import requests

url = 'https://www.usagold.com/reference/prices/silverhistory.php'

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}

response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
tables = soup.find_all('table', rules = 'all')

table = str(tables[0]) #cast table to string

df = pd.read_html(table, skiprows=2, flavor='bs4')[0]
print(df.head())
```

Comment: Upon running the last command (df = ...) I get an exception:---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-125-72f913e033f2> in <module>()
----> 1 df = pd.read_html(StringIO(table), skiprows=2, flavor='bs4')[0]

TypeError: initial_value must be str or None, not Tag

Comment: sorry I was using python2. I made an edit and it works for me on python 3 now. You don't even need StringIO