# Text 1D array into a 2D pandas DF from a webscrape

Tags: python, pandas, beautifulsoup

Hi I have done a webscrape on a table of data using the following code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame()


for row in links2get:
    url = row
    response = requests.get(url)
    html_page = response.content
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html_page, 'html.parser')
    text = soup.find_all(text=True)
    for a in soup.select('.trackM'):
        b = a.get_text()
        array = np.array(b)
        print(array)
        #reshape = ????
        #df = df.append(reshape)
```

My output of the array I have is:

```
print(array):

Table Title


Heading 1
Heading 2
Heading 3
Heading 4
Heading 5


1084
316
No
72
Yes
```

**EDIT** Sometimes there are missing values from the table so there can be an odd number of elements (eg. 5 heading columns but only 4 values).

I am hoping to reshape into a DataFrame so it looks like:

```
print(df):

Heading 1   Heading 2   Heading 3   Heading 4   Heading 5
1084           316         No          72           Yes
```

IM having trouble with the reshape so if anyone has any advice that would be great! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know the url and the title of the table you can simply do this.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_html(url, match='Table Title')[0]
```

If you have the table as text, extracted from beautiful soup. you can simply do this.

```
import pandas as pd
table_string = '''<table>
  <tr>
    <th>heading 1</th>
    <th>heading 2</th>
    <th>heading 3</th>
    <th>heading 4</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1084</td>
    <td>316</td>
    <td>No</td>
    <td>72</td>
    <td>Yes</td>
  </tr>
</table>'''

df = pd.read_html(table_string)[0]
```

output:

```
   heading 1  heading 2 heading 3  heading 4 Unnamed: 4
0       1084        316        No         72        Yes
```

Comment: Hi @visibleman. Yes i can do that however when I run the `df = pd.read_html(table_string)` i get a `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable` error. The start of my `table_string` looks like:
`<div class="InfoTrack trackM">
<h3 style="margin-bottom:15px;">Data</h3>
<table>
<tr class="fullHeader">
<th>heading 1</th>`
...

Comment: I added an index[0] to the read_html statement, as read_html returns a list.    Further I think you need to use soup to extract only the table element (and its children), without the div etc...       Even with all that ... I am not sure why you get that error.  Some basic google search seem to sugest that it might help to add the parameter flavor='bs4' to the read_html call.

Comment: And don't get me wrong, absolutely nothing wrong with trying to parse this out using your own code; The above solution was suggested as an easy timesaver, if it doesn't save you any time, then by all means go with what you have and the advice provided by Dave.

Comment: Thanks @visibleman. I am trying both methods from yourself and Dave. I have got the extraction down to the table only which is good but will try and work out why the object is not calllable. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I think the object not callable might be related to an old  pandas version?, or possibly to some missing dependency like the lxml package.  By adding the flavor parameter to the read_html call you might be able to work around the missing package....  But I haven't seen this myself,  it's just my basic understanding of the previous quick google search.

Comment: Yes i found the same. I found a solution here on stack overflow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41651350/pandas-read-html-results-in-typeerror and when I added  `df = pd.read_html(table_string.prettify(),flavor='bs4')[0]` it worked! Thanks again @visibleman

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track. Start with a Series of clean tokens though. That will make downstream simpler.

```
[e for e in b.splitlines()[1:] if len(e)]

# b.splitlines()     -> Split the text output into a list at the linebreaks.
# b.splitlines()[1:] -> Drop the first element of the list ("Table Title")
# ... if len(e)      -> Only keep the token if it has length greater than zero (i.e. not the empty string.)
```

It's critical that at this part, you're always creating a series with an even number of elements:

```
...
b = a.get_text()
s = pd.Series([e for e in b.splitlines()[1:] if len(e)])

Out[54]: 
0    Heading 1
1    Heading 2
2    Heading 3
3    Heading 4
4    Heading 5
5         1084
6          316
7           No
8           72
9          Yes
```

Now reshape directly into a DataFrame. Because we know that the number of elements in the Series is even, we can reshape into two rows of length `int(len(s) / 2)`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(s.values.reshape((2, int(len(s) / 2))))

           0          1          2          3          4
0  Heading 1  Heading 2  Heading 3  Heading 4  Heading 5
1       1084        316         No         72        Yes
```

Now, we assign the columns from the first row:

```
df.columns = df.iloc[0]

0  Heading 1  Heading 2  Heading 3  Heading 4  Heading 5
0  Heading 1  Heading 2  Heading 3  Heading 4  Heading 5
1       1084        316         No         72        Yes
```

And finally, drop the row that we used for the columns:

```
df.drop(df.index[0])

0 Heading 1 Heading 2 Heading 3 Heading 4 Heading 5
1      1084       316        No        72       Yes
```

Comment: This is great. Thanks very much @Dave. This issue that I am finiding now when looping through multiple tables is that not every table contains an even number of element. There is always 5 `Heading` rows but sometimes the data within the heading table is missing or there are two elements for 1 colum. To get around this wrote an 
`if len(s) <10:
      s.append('NA',NA','NA',NA')
      t = pd.Series(s[1:11]) `
Which is great however on a couple of loops I am getting an `TypeError: cannot concatenate object of type '<class 'str'>'; only Series and DataFrame objs are valid`

Comment: I now fixed this by adding the `(NA',NA','NA',NA')` as its own `pd.Series()`

Comment: I have realised now the issue is that sometimes there is no value in the table data therefore it is skiipping that cell as an element. Any way to get around this do you know?

Comment: Thanks for your help @Dave. I ended up being able to use the `pd.read_html` solution whihc made getting around the no value issue

Comment: Yes, that's the best way to do it. I upvoted that answer myself!